# How to prevent AddThis from modifying the URL?

Tags: share, addthis

We are using AddThis in our website for sharing to Facebook, Twitter etc.

The url we are sharing to Facebook looks like this:

http://example.com/shop/products/booklet-10-pack#.VsLsXM8od2Q.facebook

When above link in Facebook is clicked, page initially loads above url and then the url is getting changed to the below:

http://example.com/shop/products/.VsLsXM8od2Q.facebook

Is this expected behavior?

How can we prevent this without turning off Click Tracking (in AddThis) ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this url: [url cleaning](http://www.addthis.com/academy/url-cleaning/), if you set

```
clean: false
```

inside of `url-transforms`, then the original should be stored/shown

Comment: The url of the page being shared to Facebook is fine. When a user goes to Facebook and clicks on the shared-page-link in Facebook, the page starts loading the correct url, then changes to an incorrect url. Will url-transforms: {clean: false} help with this also ?

Comment: sorry for the delay in responding. This modification as I understand it has to be declared where the button is. Unfortunately if you do not have source access to the pages on the Facebook then you won't be able to modify this setting on that page. An alternative is to change the url parameters in such a way that they wont be deleted, ie change `booklet-10-pack#` to `booklet-10-pack?` or similar.